# JQuery-Flot: How to add text label for Y-axis and date label for X-axis?

Tags: jquery, flot

So basically, I have a test graph in JQuery-Flot, and instead of the normal integer axis.  I need to use text label for the Y-axis and date label for the X-axis.  Do anyone know how to do this?

Comment: [This example](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/annotating.html) does it just by adding absolutely-positioned text to the chart.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [flot api](http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/API.txt) covers both of these cases (under "Customizing the axes").  For the x-axis you'll want to use the ["time" option](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/time.html).  For the y-axis tick labels you'll want to specify the ticks option (what text should appear at each location):

```
ticks: [[0, "zero"], [1.2, "one mark"], [2.4, "two marks"]]
```